The measurablity of semicontinuous functions in Rudin's RCA 11.19
Rudin's reasoning:
11.18 Approach Regions
For $0<\alpha<1$, we define $\Omega_\alpha$ to be the union of the disc $D(0 ; \alpha)$ and the line segments from $z=1$ to points of $D(0 ; \alpha)$.
In other words, $\Omega_\alpha$ is the smallest convex open set that contains $D(0;\alpha)$ and has the point 1 in its boundary. Near $z=1, \Omega_\alpha$ is an angle, bisected by the radius of $U$ that terminates at 1 , of opening $2 \theta$, where $\alpha=\sin \theta$. Curves that approach 1 within $\Omega_\alpha$ cannot be tangent to $T$. Therefore $\Omega_\alpha$ is called a nontangential approach region, with vertex 1.
The regions $\Omega_\alpha$ expand when $\alpha$ increases. Their union is $U$, their intersection is the radius $[0,1)$.
Rotated copies of $\Omega_\alpha$, with vertex at $e^{i t}$, will be denoted by $e^{i t} \Omega_\alpha$.
11.19 Maximal Functions
If $0<\alpha<1$ and $u$ is any complex function with domain $U$, its nontangential maximal function $N_\alpha u$ is defined on $T$ by
$$
\left(N_\alpha u\right)\left(e^{i t}\right)=\sup \left\{|u(z)|: z \in e^{i t} \Omega_\alpha\right\} .
$$
Similarly, the radial maximal function of $u$ is
$$
\left(M_{\mathrm{rad}} u\right)\left(e^{i t}\right)=\sup \left\{\left|u\left(r e^{i t}\right)\right|: 0 \leq r<1\right\} .
$$
If $u$ is continuous and $\lambda$ is a positive number, then the set where either of these maximal functions $\leq \lambda$ is a closed subset of $T$. Consequently, $N_\alpha u$ and $M_{\mathrm{rad}} u$ are lower semicontinuous on $T$; in particular, they are measurable.
My Question:
How can I deduce that the preimage is closed?

I guess that $T$ denotes the unit circle of $\mathbb{C}$.
The definition of $N_\alpha u$ can be written
$$\forall w \in T,~\left(N_\alpha u\right)\left(w\right)
=\sup \left\{|u(wz)|: z \in \Omega_\alpha\right\}.$$
Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{T}$. For every $w \in T$,
$$\left(N_\alpha u\right)\left(w\right) \le \lambda 
\iff \forall z \in \Omega_\alpha,~|u(wz)| \le \lambda.$$
Thus
$$\left(N_\alpha u\right)^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda]) 
= \bigcap_{z \in \Omega_\alpha}\{w \in T : |u(wz)| \le \lambda\}$$
is closed, by continuity of the maps $w \mapsto |u(wz)|$.
